# Downloading Large Folders From Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I need to download around 100 GBs of data from Dropbox; preferably in one bulk download that will maintain the sub-folder structure contained within the main parent folder.

Does anybody have a solution for downloading so many files in one go? When I use the typical "download folder" method it does not actually download (I believe Dropbox has a 20Gb limit on such downloads).

Answer (score 2):

There a few solutions that I found for connecting via FTP method for connecting to/from Dropbox, but excluding those who offer a trial-version, I only found only one that has a free membership without time-limits: MultiCloud.

There is a 2TB Traffic Limit for [the Lifetime Free Plan](https://www.multcloud.com/price), but that is pretty high, and if you need unlimited traffic, it is only $7.99.

They even provide a  4-step tutorial on getting it set up [HERE](https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/connect-to-dropbox-via-ftp-0708.html)